# Clarification regarding Class and functions

Tags: typescript, function, class

First I apologize if there is already a question regarding this topic, I can't seem to find an answer. I just need a clarification, maybe I'm missing something. I'm kind of new at this. Thanks!

So I have a class and a function that both returns a greeting.

If I can also use the class' greeting method, why or when should I use a function?

```
class Greeter{ 
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName:string, public lastName:string) { 
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
    greetName() { 
        return "Hello, " + this.fullName;
    }
}

//this function is outside of class greeter
function greeter(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    return "Hello, " + firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the function `greeter` when you haven't created an object of the class `Greeter`.

You can use the function `Greeter#greetName` only after `constructor` is called, so the object will be created, otherwise it will fail.

If it is very confusing for you that the function greeter is outside the class, you can put it inside, but mark it as `static` function, then you will be able to call it as `Greeter.greeter` without creating an object of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Functions inside of classes are called "methods". Those methods are tied to an instance of a class, which is called an object. Normally, methods are used to return or modify the objects state.

Functions outside of classes are normally used to perform some action without mutating state. For example they calculate something and then return the value.

As @Rufi already pointed out, you can only use the greeter method after creating an instance of the class (via the constructor). That does not make a lot of sense in this case.

In your case, the difference between the two examples given is that one is tied to the state of an object (by accessing this.fullname) while the other one is pure (not tied to any state, it just uses the given parameters to create a new value).

I hope this helps!